# How to use query function to exclude names based on criteria from another sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, match, spreadsheet, textjoin, multiple-matches

How to use query function to exclude names based on criteria from another sheet ? Thank you

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Yl-oBui4ji6AzGg47FAe68fi2PqHTUC08kYhBMtB2DY/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=QUERY({A2:B}, "where not Col1 matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, Criteria!A:A)&"'")
```

[image]